# Angular Material 15: Vertical/inverted slider

Tags: angular, angular-material

Due to the migration guide, Angular Material 15 no longer supports vertical/inverted sliders: https://material.angular.io/guide/mdc-migration#slider

In my case, I need the vertical inverted slider because it represents some kind of roller. So it is not possible to just use a "normal" slider.

Is there a way to also get a vertical inverted slider with Angular Material 15? Or does someone know a similar component?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can still import old slider from a "legacy" import

```
import {MatLegacySliderModule } from '@angular/material/legacy-slider';
```

Comment: Oh, I missed that one in the migration guide, thanks! But of course these legacy components are already deprecated and therefore will be removed in a future release, I think. But hopefully there will be another solution available when this happens...

Comment: It will be removed in version 17. Hopefull angular team will provide better API for vertical alignment.

Comment: This does not seem to work anymore, can you help me please.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77634889/angular-material-17-vertical-slider